Oxygen.jl CORS and Websockets
When using the example Oxygen.jl CORS middeleware with a websocket connection I get:
│    ArgumentError: invalid JSON at byte position 0 while parsing type Any: UnexpectedEOF

On  r = handle(req)
Should I setup a separate router to bypass CORS for websocket connections?
